Automating the moving of files
I'm running a simulation for a project. 
Each simulation run generates many .dat files. 
So, essentially, I'm getting Z_image_000.dat to Z_image_276.dat. 
I'm running multiple simulations in a day, so I'm getting many sets of these. Each time after every run, I need to clear out the folder before doing another run, else it overwrites. Yes, I could simply do it manually and create a new folder and drag and drop those files in. 
But what I'm thinking of doing is finding a way to automate this process.
What I want this script to do is:

Create a new folder, named according to the current date and time.
Move those Z_image_NNN.dat files into this new folder. 
The directories for the source folder where these Z_image files are created in is /home/gate/020824. 
I want a new folder created in this directory (essentially the destination directory?) e.g.,/home/gate/020824/(folder named by current date and time)


Yes, I could do it manually, but it offers a small efficiency boost, multiplied by many runs!
I am trying to write a shell script that I can run to move files
with the file name containing 'z_image' to a newly created folder. 
I have gotten the following script from ChatGPT, but it does not seem to work.
#!/bin/bash

#Define the source directory and the destination directory
SOURCE_DIR="/path/to/your/files"
DEST_DIR="/path/to/destination_folder"

#Create the destination directory if it does not exist
mkdir -p "$DEST_DIR"

#Move files containing 'example' in their name to the destination directory
mv "$SOURCE_DIR"/*example* "$DEST_DIR"

I have no experience in coding, and would appreciate any help or explanations!
OS is Ubuntu.

What does "does not seem to work" mean exactly? You have changed the paths in the first lines to match your system and replaced example by z_image?

@DonHolgo Yes I have inserted the path to the folder containing those files, as well as replaced example with z_image. However when I run the script, the files did not move, and i simply got an error mentioning that (my input path) is a directory, which makes me think, is it not supposed to be one?

Please [edit] your question and add: i) an example input directory. Show us the output of ls -F on that directory. ii) the expected output. Show us the files you expect to be moved, and files you expect to NOT be moved. iii) show us the exact script you run and describe how it fails.

Are you sure you even want a script? What you describe is a single command: mv /path/to/source/dir/z_image* /path/to/target/dir/.

@terdon I dont have access to the PC at the moment, but perhaps I can simply explain what I'm trying to do here simply.
So basically I'm running a simulation for a project. Each simulation run generates many .dat files. So essentially I'm getting Z_image_000.dat to Z_image_276.dat. Im running multiple simulations in a day, so Im getting many sets of these. Each time after every run, I need to clear out the folder before doing another run, else it overwrites. Yes, I could simply do it manually and create a new folder and drag and drop those files in...(cont.)

@terdon (continued..) But what I'm thinking of doing is to find a way to automate this process. What I want this script to do is 1) Create a new folder, named according to the current date and time. 2) Move those Z_image.dat files into this new folder. The directories for the source folder where these Z_image files are created in is /home/gate/020824 . I want a new folder created in this directory (essentially the destination directory?) eg. /home/gate/020824/(folder named by current date and time). Yes I could do it manually, but it offers a small efficiency boost, multiplied by many runs!

Ah. Please add all this to the question body since comments are hard to read, easy to miss and can be deleted without warning. Also, my apologies, you had included the detail about the date right there in the question, but I missed it since I was looking at the code, my bad.

An alias to timestamp="$(date +"%F_%T")" && mkdir $timestamp && mv Z_image_* $timestamp?

(1) I notice that you have a directory named 020824.  That looks suspiciously like the date of this question in DDMMYY format.  I know that there are strongly felt preferences whether dates should be written MM/DD or DD/MM.  But, personal preferences and aesthetics aside, I recommend the YMD order for file- (and directory-) names.  Note that there will be a 020924 next month and a 020825 next year, but today is 060824.  … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) …  My point is that you will benefit from using a date format where ordinary directory order (lexicographical sort order) is the same as chronological order.  Also, if you’re too young to remember Y2K, you’re young enough that you might still be alive in 2100 — so use four-digit years.  (And, for readability, consider YYYY-MM-DD format.)  (2) Obligatory xkcd.
